# PrimeFaces: change the default height of the selectOneMenu label border

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to change the default height to the selectOneMenu (the border of the label too) component in PrimeFaces but I am facing problem that the border is not being changed. How can I change the default height of the selectOneMenu label border?

**CSS Code**

```
<style type="text/css">                    
   .selectOperationOneMenu.ui-selectonemenu {
      min-width: 30% !important;
     margin-top: 20px;
   }
   .selectOperationOneMenu.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
      height: 25px !important;
      line-height: 25px !important;
   }
   .selectOperationOneMenu.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger {
      height: 25px !important;
   }                    
</style>
```

**PrimeFaces xhtml code**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu"  
                 scrollHeight="100" 
                 value="#{viewEventStatusController.operationId}" 
                 autoWidth="false"
                 style="#{componentUnit.style}" 
                 styleClass="selectOperationOneMenu" 
                 disabled="#{!chat.valid}" 
                 rendered="#{componentUnit.type == 'selectOneMenu'}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{viewEventStatusController.convertJsonToList(chat.operations)}"
                 var="operation" 
                 itemValue="#{viewEventStatusController.getOperationIndex(operation)}"
                 itemLabel="#{operation}" />
  <p:ajax event="change"
          update="@form"
          resetValues="true" 
          listener="#{viewEventStatusController.changeSelectOnMenueOperation(chat, componentUnit)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image]

Comment: You talk about the default width but it seems that you try to accomplish something with the height. Please be more concise: what do you want to achieve, what do you expect to happen, what does actually happen?

Comment: @thunderhook: sorry to this typo. Yes I am meant the height

Comment: Removing the height from `.selectOperationOneMenu.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger {` works for me with primefaces version 6.1 in Firefox, Chrome, IE11 and Edge - can't test on Safari currently.

What primefaces version are you using? If you also use PF6.1 your corporate CSS might influence the component - try to inspect via developer tools. If you can't figure it out yourself, edit your post and deliver all "CSS rules" from developer tools, I'm here to help.